# Tabbed Activity: Trouble with getting images from imageview

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with getting images from my imageviews in a tabbed activity. My tabbed activity consists of 365 pages, each with an image on them. Now I have a button which I use to save the images as a file to the internal storage. But whenever I press on that button it saves the image from the previous page, so not the current focused one.

Here is my code to save the image:

```
ImageView imageView;
            imageView = (ImageView) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Bitmap pictureBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            String filename = dates[mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1];
            Log.d("saved date:", dates[mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1]);
            File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "test");

            FileOutputStream outputStream;

            try {
                outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

UPDATE:

Here is the code from my onCreateView from my `PlaceholderFragment` class:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Log.d("LOADING IMAGE:", String.valueOf(imgs[getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)]));
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgs[getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)]);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(dates[getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)]);
        TextView weekNumber = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.weekNumber);
        weekNumber.setText("Week " + weekNumbers[getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)]);



        FloatingActionButton fab4 = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab4);
        fab4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("FAB4", "CLICK");
                Utilities util = new Utilities();
                util.saveImage(rootView, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER),dates, getContext());
            }
        });
```

Here is the code from my `util` class:

```
public class Utilities {
public void saveImage(View rootView, int pageNumber, String[] dates, Context context){
    ImageView imageView;
    imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap pictureBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    String filename = dates[pageNumber];
    Log.d("saved date:", dates[pageNumber]);
    //File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "test");

    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My fragment_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="example.test.sliderappv002.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="placeholderDay"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weekNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="placeholderWeek" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My LogCat output:

```
03-29 09:42:17.597 6343-6343/example.test.sliderappv002 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: example.test.sliderappv002, PID: 6343
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at example.test.sliderappv002.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:323)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:664)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:731)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: please post the button press code..

Comment: Are you using a PagerAdapter with your mViewPager?

Comment: @kishumewara That is the code that is executed when the button is pressed.

Comment: @DmitriTimofti yes I am using an SectionPagerAdapter

Comment: can you also show your fragment_main layout and the full logcat output?

Comment: Added, also sorry for the weird formatting, wouldn't work with me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `PagerAdapter` - just set the button click listener inside the `instantiateItem()` method.

If you're using `FragmentPagerAdapter` - set the button listener inside the `Fragment#onCreateView()` method of the fragment that you're returning in `FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem()`

Code snippet:

```
public static class YourAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ...

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return YourFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}

public static class YourFragment extends Fragment {

...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ...
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //save image code goes here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
The previous solution assumed that you have a FAB inside your fragment layout, but it looks like you have only one FloatingActionButton defined in the activity layout...in this case, the simplest way to obtain the ImageView from the current fragment is to to something like this

```
View rootview = ((Fragment) mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager, mViewPager.getCurrentItem())).getView();
if (rootView != null)
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

probably not the cleanest solution, but it's a solution.

Comment: I tried to set the onClickListener in the `Fragment#onCreateView()` but I got an error:
    `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'`

Comment: did you initialize the button inside onCreateView?

`View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
            FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);`

Comment: Yes I did. But I have `final View rootView` because otherwise I can't acces the rootview from within the `onClickListener`

Comment: can you update your post with the code from onCreateView?